# Chances of US tourist visa acceptance after getting Canadian PR?

Tags: usa, visa, canada

I was in the US on an F-1 visa and after living there for nearly 6 years (education + work on OPT), I left the US to go to Canada before my US visa/STEM OPT expired. Never been denied visa/entry to US or any other country. I am a citizen of a third country.

I moved to Canada with a permanent residency (PR) and would like to know if I applied for a US tourist visa (in Canada) immediately after moving there, are there higher/lower chances of rejection or are they indifferent to my immigration status elsewhere? Does having the PR strengthen my ties to another country or do they weaken them because I'm not in my home country?

Or should I wait till I get my Canadian citizenship to qualify for entry without visa? Having a visa denial on my record will prove troublesome later on? Might as well not take the risk then?

I need the visa for occasional tourist visits or visiting friends etc.

Comment: Short answer is no one knows. What I find is if you have a genuine reason to go to the US, they will accept your application. PR/Non PR. First World, Third world doesn't really matter. I have applied for it when I was on a work permit and was approved.

Comment: If you get permanent residence in Canada, then Canada *is* your home country.

Comment: @user102008 thanks for your input. Sometimes officials can mean home country to be the current country of citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

Your chances are pretty good, provided you have good ties to Canada, especially a stable source of income and place of residence.  As noted in a comment, your status as a permanent resident of Canada means that the visa officer will consider your ties to Canada, not to your country of citizenship.

Having a visa refusal on your record could prove troublesome later on, mostly when you try to enter the US or any country that asks about visa refusals in other countries.  However, unless your current circumstances are particularly unsettled, a refusal is probably unlikely.